# How can I keep my app alive forever without VOIP in IOS?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

My app includes functionality that requires it to run in the background. The app needs to monitor the accelerometer while in the background so that it will notice when a fall is detected.

I used VOIP to add functionality "Keep alive forever", but  my app was rejected. So is there any other way to run my app in the background forever?

**Updated**:

Apple recommend to remove VOIP or add more functionality of VOIP in my code.So I read some tutorial to add VOIP functionality.

[https://www.twilio.com/docs/client/ios](http://www.twilio.com/docs/client/ios)

http://www.raywenderlich.com/29948/backgrounding-for-ios

but get confused.So please give some solutions.so that my app get accepted by apple.

Comment: What you're proposing to do is just against Apple's policies. Re-think your app concept, sorry.

Comment: its not possible. same problem i fetched. i update my location in background and my app alive in background mode. one more thing if you continuously update your location then app rejected.

Comment: it is security app and require to be run in background .This is a main functionality of my app.so please suggest any other way to do so.Can i do it with location updater? is it accepted ?

Comment: Re-read the comments above - you can't do it. It's against the App Store policies.

Comment: can i do it with VOIP? @AshleyMills

Comment: Your app isn't a VOIP app, so no.

Comment: VOIP means " Voice over Internet Protocol" allows the user to make phone calls using an Internet connection. so if i add that calling to my code than is it possible? because i have already added messaging service provided by twillio.@AshleyMills

Answer (score 0):

You can try CocoaPods library `KeepAppAliveForever`：

```
  pod 'KeepAppAliveForever'
```

or [this](https://github.com/huuang/KeepAppAliveForever) github repository.

Answer (score -1):

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/iPhoneAppProgrammingGuide.pdf

I found this website download this pdf and go to page 60 and read from there you secret hides, if you are desperate it will take some reading. LOL.

Have fun reading. :D
Hope this helped you.

I did some code research

```
- (void) backgroundForever {
        backgroundTaskID = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
             [self backgroundForever]; 
        }];
}

- (void) stopBackgroundTask {
       UIApplication *application = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
       if(backgroundTaskID != -1)
            [application endBackgroundTask:backgroundTaskID];
}
```

So basically we start a new background task when the current background task ends. You call stopBackgroundTask to whenever you want to stop the background task. It's up to your application logic, Eg you can call this in applicationDidEnterForeground.

It works, but i'm not sure if your app will pass Apple review.

From AJTech

Comment: I already used this code .but it works unto 10 minutes. @AJ Tech